# Tinymce list of shortcodes button

Tags: shortcode, tinymce

does someone know about tutorial or how to do button with list of shortcodes in tinymce? For example like in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmzUuwW9AU4 (This function in the video is exatly what I want to). Same function have a lot of templates on themeforest.

Thx for reading my question.

Comment: An intensive and well written tutorial for this matter can be found here on this website - https://paulund.co.uk/add-button-tinymce-shortcodez

Answer (score 1):

[Shortcode Ninja](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcode-ninja/) plugin will give you an example of how it can be done (creates a dropdown of all the shortcodes from Woothemes.com.)

Also worth looking at [this tutorial](http://marquex.es/387/adding-a-select-box-to-wordpress-tinymce-editor) for a more general purpose approach.